# How to insert from a select query with dynamic partitioning on a column in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql, hiveql

I'm trying to insert a computed partition.
The partition's value needs to be computed from a key column.
Assume that key_2 in the example always has 10 characters. The last 3 character I want to use in partition. I need dynamic partitioning.

My table is similar to this:

```
DROP TABLE exampledb.exampletable;
CREATE TABLE exampledb.exampletable (
    key_1 STRING,
    key_2 STRING,
    col_1 STRING,
    col_2 STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (my_part STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
;
```

I've tried multiple variants of the HQL below:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE exampledb.exampletable
PARTITION(my_part)
SELECT 
    key_1,
    key_2,
    col_1,
    col_2,
    SUBSTR(key_2, -3) as my_part    -- not sure how to insert partition
FROM exampledb.exampletable_temp;
```

I couldn't figure out what's the correct solution for this.
I always get a syntax error.

Does enyone know the solution for this?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
FAILED: SemanticException Partition spec {my_part=null} contains non-partition columns
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've also tried tried to avoid NULL values by using this solution (as it was proposed below, but the error is the same):

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hvdb_as_aqua_guk_core.hvtb_aqua_guk_finding_mgn
PARTITION(my_part) ( key_1, key_2, col_1, col_2, my_part    )
SELECT 
        key_1,
        key_2,
        col_1,
        col_2,
        SUBSTR(key_2, -3) as my_part    -- not sure how to insert partition
FROM hvdb_as_aqua_guk_core.hvtb_aqua_guk_finding_mgn_temp2
WHERE key_2 IS NOT NULL
    AND SUBSTR(key_2, -3) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I've updated the question...

Answer (score 1):

You should specify explicitly all the column names you are inserting into. For example, your command should be something like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE exampledb.exampletable
PARTITION(my_part)(key_1, key_2, col_1, col_2, my_part)
SELECT 
    key_1,
    key_2,
    col_1,
    col_2,
    SUBSTR(key_2, -3)
FROM exampledb.exampletable_temp;
```

This should work.

**UPDATE**

I tried to create a test case, and `INSERT OVERWRITE` doesn't seem to work, but `INSERT INTO` is working. A workaround could be to delete all data from the destination table with `TRUNCATE TABLE exampledb.exampletable`, or delete all data from a specific partition with `TRUNCATE TABLE test6 PARTITION (my_part = '001');`, then run an `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO exampledb.exampletable
PARTITION(my_part)(key_1, key_2, col_1, col_2, my_part)
SELECT
    key_1,
    key_2,
    col_1,
    col_2,
    SUBSTR(key_2, -3)
FROM exampledb.exampletable_temp;
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution gives this error: 
FAILED: ParseException line 5:32 cannot recognize input near '(' 'key_1' ',' in statement

Comment: Now I saw your update in the question, have you checked that `SUBSTR(key_2, -3)` always returns a non-NULL value?

Comment: This key_2 is a part of a complex key for a record. The value is present in every record...

Comment: I tried to create a test case, with `INSERT INTO TABLE exampledb.exampletable` it works, but with `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE exampledb.exampletable` it doesn't work. If you want to delete all your data in your destination table before inserting new data, you could run `TRUNCATE TABLE exampledb.exampletable` followed by the `INSERT INTO` statement.

Comment: Be careful that all means ALL. If you want to delete data on only a specific partition, you should use this syntax `TRUNCATE TABLE exampledb.exampletable PARTITION (my_part = '001');`

Comment: I've to implement this pattern (step 3): http://letsexplorehadoop.blogspot.hu/2016/05/upsert-in-hive-3-step-process.html
That's why I can't truncate table or give the partition with value (as a "parameter") like you did: "my_part = '001'".
I have to use dynamic partitions.

Comment: I've put a nullcheck to this value to filter out the corrupted records, but the result is the same: 
"...
WHERE key_2 IS NOT NULL
    AND SUBSTR(key_2, -3) IS NOT NULL"